# How do I remove the double quotes encapsulating each row of my custom CSV?

Tags: php, csv

```
  function create_csv_string($data2) {


if (!$fp = fopen('php://temp', 'w+')) return FALSE;

   foreach ($data2 as $line)   fputcsv($fp,str_replace('"',' ',$line), ";");
   rewind($fp);
   return stream_get_contents($fp);
}
```

The csv output is as below for every row:

"
4292;1;1000;E;P;C;C;1111;Webshop_4235;13/04/2018;COM;;;GBP;;140100;;;0;;;;;;;;;;"

I would like to not have the double quotes at the beginning and end of the row.

Comment: This is how CSV works. If you have special characters in your values, they get surrounded with double quotes.

Comment: Also, the second parameter to fputcsv is supposed to be an array. I'm surprised that don't get an error there.

Comment: Perhaps fwrite() could help, if you are willing to manually build your CSV structure.